# Question about solving $x^2 < 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

When you have that you basically have:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2} & < \sqrt{1} \iff\\
|x| & < \pm 1
\end{align*}
Doesn't that give you 2 options? $|x| < 1, |x| <-1$?
The latter is false because $|x|$ is always positive right?

So to solve this $-1 < x < 1$. Correct?

Comment: If I wrote $\sqrt{1^2}$ would you have $\pm 1$ or $|1|$?

Comment: $|x|<1$ means that $\pm x < 1$, so $x<1$ and $-x<1$. Manipulating those gives you the result you state in your last line.

Comment: The square root function always returns the positive answer.  There is a difference between $x^2=1$ and $x=\sqrt{1}$.

Comment: What would “$|x| < \pm 1$” even *mean*? For equations, $x=\pm a$ means “$x=a$ or $x=-a$”, but for inequalities, putting “or” between the two cases leads to a rather strange statement (which is definitely not equivalent to the one you started with).